# How can I count the duration of my Skype video calls?

Tags: video, skype

So I'm curious how much time I spent on Skype video chatting so far. I can't go through my history and check that because I unfortunately need to delete history since some people are too nosy.

So question is simple: does Skype count how much you've used video call so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Skype uses an SQlite database for storing your data. I tried this on a Mac, but it's probably very similar for Windows.

- OS X: Locate the file `main.db` in *~/Library/Application Support/Skype/profile-name*
- Windows: `%appdata%`, then */Roaming/Skype/profile-name*

Open it in an SQlite browser of your choice. Run the query:

```
SELECT SUM(duration) FROM calls;
```

… and there you go. The result is in seconds. I can't seem to find a reliable query to differ between video calls and voice-only calls. The `video_disabled` field is always unused.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Except what is that, hours or minutes?

Comment: @BojanK It's very likely measured in seconds. I actually found another [Skype log viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html) for Windows that might help you as well.

Comment: But check this out: http://i.imgur.com/1sxTr.jpg this.. well I don't think I've spent on Skype THAT much!

Comment: @BojanK I re-checked. The `Videos` table seems to be unreliable. I was only able to find my video calls in `Calls`. Maybe make a cross-check with the Skype Log Viewer.

Comment: But that's just normal calls. Maybe the video calls is counted twice, from each person. Timestamps are doubled it seems. Skype log viewer is useless, no video calls there.

Comment: @BojanK Skype unfortunately does not seem to make a distinction between "video call" and "call" whatsoever. So if it's not in the database, I highly doubt there's a way to find out.